# Migrated to .NET 4.0 however MicrosoftAjax.debug.js still says version 3.5

Tags: .net, ajax, .net-4.0, microsoft-ajax

Recently upgraded the entire project to .NET 4.0 but when I debug javascript (using FireBug or Developer tools for IE9) it says the javascript file MicrosoftAjax.debug.js is still version 3.5 - is this an issue?

```
// Name: MicrosoftAjax.debug.js 
// Assembly: AjaxControlToolkit
// Version: 3.5.40412.0
// FileVersion: 3.5.40412.2
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download new version of AjaxControlToolkit. Upgrading project does not apply to additional assemblies, libraries etc.

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Please give feedback in comment if i helped.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought this was a MS assembly that would be updated with the migration.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried bindingRedirect ?  [Assembly BindingRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx)

from MSDN

> A binding redirection in an application configuration file for a
>   unified .NET Framework assembly cancels the unification for that
>   assembly. For example, an application that referenced types in
>   System.XML and was built using runtime version 1.0 would contain
>   static references to the System.XML assembly that shipped with runtime
>   version 1.0. If you wanted to redirect the binding reference to point
>   to the System.XML assembly that shipped with runtime version 1.1, you
>   would put redirect information in the application configuration file.

syntax

```
<bindingRedirect  
   oldVersion="old assembly version"
   newVersion="new assembly version"/>
```

eg:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```